# App chooser Intent doesn't appear in android emulator

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I a using this code yo show the installed browser application:

```
Log.i(TAG, "Entered startImplicitActivation()");

// TODO - Create a base intent for viewing a URL
// (HINT: second parameter uses Uri.parse())

Intent baseIntent = null;
baseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));

// TODO - Create a chooser intent, for choosing which Activity
// will carry out the baseIntent
// (HINT: Use the Intent class' createChooser() method)

Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(baseIntent, "Choose App");

// TODO - Start the chooser Activity, using the chooser intent

Log.i(TAG, "Chooser Intent Action:" + chooserIntent.getAction());
startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

But it opens the link directly in the default browser app. why?

### edit

I have created and installed another simple browser app, that has this `intent-fiilter`:

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your emulator have only one app which accepts those kind of Intents , In your case only one browser is present so it directly redirects.

try by adding default category once and check 
**EDIT**

```
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
   </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved the problem was by adding `android:host="www.google.com"`to the in the myBrowser app.  From what I understand, when I was launching the chooser and the it's associated intent it was looking for an app with `ACTION_VIEW` and the capability of the URL "http://www.google.com".  It was not finding myBrowser because it was only set to receive the "http" (`android:scheme="http"`), adding the host  allowed my Intent Chooser to recognize the myBrowser app.

Please can someone correct me if this explanation is incorrect.